# Where to find "Enable Debugging of Unmanaged Code" to be able to edit the code while the system is running?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

In an older version of Visual Studio (Like the one at home, guess 2013), I am able to edit my code while the system is running but I can't continue (and I don't want to continue). While *step-ping* through my code, I just want to start typing and once I finish editing then to recompile.

The advantage is that while typing I can hoover my mouse and watch values/structures of the variables and edit according. It's a nice guide sometimes, like a reminder or notes.

**Why my Visual Studio 2015 prevents me from editing my code**? saying:

> Changes are not allowed when unmanaged debugging is enabled

**P.S** my *[**Edit and Continue**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yty6a48.aspx)* option is enabled as suggested everywhere on the internet. And there is no *Enable Unmanaged debugging option* for 2015 like suggested here for 2010 [**How to: Enable Debugging of Unmanaged Code**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdw0c6sf(v=vs.100).aspx)

**Edit**: It's a C#/C++ application. I didn't start the project from scratch and it's a huge one. I start it as Debugger and sometimes Release. Doesn't work on both (I don't care about the Release)

How my settings under `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General` look like:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What kind of project, and how are you starting the debugger?

Comment: @slaks it's a C#/C++ sort of projects. And I edited my post to add that

Comment: What exactly is the project?

Comment: _What kind of project is it?_ C# application? WinForms? WPF? C++ application?  There is no such thing as a "C#/C++ application" project.

Comment: Oh, It's a WPF @slak and the solution has other projects like C++ console. I care about the main which is a WPF

Comment: If it really is a WPF application, that checkbox should be there.

Comment: Should it exactly say _Enable Debugging of Unmanaged Code_? If not, could you show me where? I added printscreens. Please and thanks @slak

Comment: use native compatibility mode when you want to break ok C++ code. Also right click on the project and  check "enable native debugging" in the project properties.  Those two things should allow you to debug c++ (not edit and continue, just normal debugging)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're in the completely wrong place; that's the system-wide debug options.

As explained in the post you linked to, you need to go to the Debug tab in Project Properties.

Comment: But I went there already and it is not there.. There is only three: _Enable native code debugging_ , _Enable SQL Server Debugging_, _Enable the Visual Studio hosting process_ under `properties -> Debug`

Comment: _Enable native code debugging_ is what you're looking for.

Comment: The error says "Changes ... is enabled" So I disabled it (it was enabled) but didn't work. However, worked after restarting the whole thing :))))))))))))))) thanks :))))

Comment: Just to clarify, this needs done in the C# project, not just the C++/CLI project.

Answer (score 3):

use native compatibility mode when you want to break ok C++ code. Also right click on the project and  check "enable native debugging" in the project properties.  Those two things should allow you to debug c++ (not edit and continue, just normal debugging)

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2022, you need to add
`<EnableUnmanagedDebugging>true</EnableUnmanagedDebugging>`

in your vcxproj files (under PropertyGroup Condition subset)