# Debug Unit tests C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper

When I debug a C++ test with Visual Studio 2017, (using ReSharper) and try to know the value of any variable, I get the following message:

```
Inspection of unmanaged type 'Dataset**' requires unmanaged debugging to be enabled.  Please set the debugger type to 'Mixed' and try again
```

Of course I have the debugger set to 'Mixed', also tried 'Auto' and 'Native Only' with the same result.

Is there a way to inspect variables in this situation?

Comment: Have you tried setting the debugger to "Native Only" to make progress.

Comment: Yes, 'Native Only' gives the same message

Comment: May be a dup of, or related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989182/where-to-find-enable-debugging-of-unmanaged-code-to-be-able-to-edit-the-code-w

Comment: @Eljay, thanks, I've tried the suggestions on that one with no success

Comment: Since the message is talking about unmanaged and managed debugging, I have to ask: Does this application involve either C# or .NET code? And are you using the C++ version of Resharper (which I didn't know existed until now)

Comment: @parktomatoni, yes, and yes, the app is a mix of C++ unmanaged and .NET code, with CLI and C#, and I am using R# C++