# DisplayAlert throws win32 exception after closing new window

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I open new window:

```
void method1(){
    wHandle = new Window(new MyPage());
    Application.Current.OpenWindow(wHandle);
}
```

and then close it in another method:

```
void method2(){
    Application.Current.CloseWindow(wHandle);
}
```

After i do this i try to display alert and got win32 exception.

I checked wheter the window does not stay in app's windows pool, but it does not. I've got no idea what would be the problem. Thanks for any help.

Image of exception warning:

[image: Image of exception warning]

When i try to open new instance of VS as it suggests that warning prompt just infinitely freezes.

I have mixed debugging enabled:

[image]

But the warning still pops up.

Comment: Any specific details in that win32 exception that you'd care to share? There should at the least be an error code with it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The only thing it says is, that debugger is attached but is not configured to handle this unhandled exception.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989182/where-to-find-enable-debugging-of-unmanaged-code-to-be-able-to-edit-the-code-w

Comment: @HansPassant I have mixed debugging ON, yet still getting that warning.

Comment: Odd problem.  But then again "infinitely freezes" isn't exact healthy either.  Disable anti-malware, repair the install, update VS, that sort of stuff.

Comment: Is this the only place, where you use reference to that window? Is this all the code that is being executed?

Comment: So, not to derail this conversation, but where exactly is this moogical `DisplayAlert` I was promised in the title of this question? Actually, instead of answering that, could you make a minimal yet fully compilable project that shows this issue and put it on github somewhere so we can actually debug it?

Comment: @Blindy So i chaotically somehow recreated the bug -> [link](https://github.com/Ponny159/DispayAlertBug)

Comment: @Levyi I tested the code you provided. It works well on Android. But for Windows, after closing new window and then click the button of DisplayAlert, the old window just flashed back. It seems to be a bug of MAUI. You can raise it on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems to be MAUI bug.

I use new page instead of new window, that works fine but it's not ideal from user's perspective.

Question can be closed.